# posts_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end has_many :comments dependant: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently working on the Blog app in Ruby on Rails and encountered this error. This occurs whenever I attempt to view localhost:3000/posts/ via my browser.

Here's my posts_controller.rb file:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
     has_many :comments  dependant: :destroy
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

Any ideas?
It's only since I entered line 8 that I've had this problem.

```
 has_many :comments  dependant: :destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `,` below :

```
has_many :comments,  dependent: :destroy
```

Read [`has_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) also to see the correct examples.

Comment: Awesome! Can't believe it was **that** simple.
Getting this error now: ArgumentError in PostsController#index

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :comments,  dependent: :destroy
```

Goes in the Post model, not the controller

Comment: I'd put in both for some reason.
In hindsight, not really sure why. Cheers.